# QueryDSL - Sum where a join is involed

Tags: java, querydsl

Given the following classes:

```
class User {
    @OneToMany
    Set<Transaction> transactions
}

class Transaction {
     BigDecimal money;
}
```

I'm stumped how to perform an aggregate, as the functions don't appear to be available on a the following query:

```
QUser $user = QUser.user;
QTransaction $transaction = QTransaction.transaction;
query().from($user)
    .innerJoint($user.transactions, $transaction)
    .where($user.eq(myUser))
    // Now what?
```

As a bonus -- is this possible if the `money` is persisted as a Joda Money type, rather than as a BigDecimal?

(I'm using [UserType's Joda Money](http://blog.jadira.co.uk/blog/2012/1/19/release-jadira-usertype-300cr1-with-support-for-joda-money-0.html) support to facilitate persistence)

Comment: You mean singleResult(transaction.money.sum()); ?

Comment: Ah!  SingleResult -- thank you.  Please post as an answer so I may accept.  Also, is it possible to perform this, using JodaMoney instead of BigDecimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
QUser $user = QUser.user;
QTransaction $transaction = QTransaction.transaction;
query().from($user)
    .innerJoin($user.transactions, $transaction) //inner join clause
    .where($user.eq(myUser))
    .singleResult($transaction.money.sum());
```

Querydsl doesn't have (yet) direct support for Joda Money, so using Joda Money the sum() method won't be available directly.